# Can a sanitary vent take a jog around an obstacle?

Tags: drain-waste-vent

I have a sanitary stack running through a bathroom but enclosed by drywall.  The enclosure takes up quite a bit of space in the bathroom but without it the stack would be visibly running through the room.   The toilet in this bathroom is the highest fixture on the stack, so above the bathroom floor it is just a vent.  When I renovate this bathroom can I jog the vent, just above the level where this toilet drains into it, so it runs through the adjacent wall instead of through the room, and then jog it back at ceiling level so it rejoins the existing stack to go through the roof?  I do not want to mess around with the roof or to open up walls in the room below this.  I'd just like to regain the space wasted by this pipe running through the bathroom by rerouting it and rejoining the existing pipe below and above.   Any issues with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The magic number is:

6" above the flood rim of the highest fixture on the floor served by the vent.

Unless you have a very strange bathroom, that highest flood rim is probably the sink in the bathroom, not the toilet in the bathroom.

Vents are to be "vertical" (which is defined as 45 degrees or more) up to that level, after which they can be diverted "horizontal" (2% slope back to the drain they serve.)

Comment: Thanks.  Good answer.  I do have a VERY strange bathroom.  1896 home, no utilities originally, many generations of major and minor renovations.  But it is not strange in the particular way you highlighted.  The sink also drains there.   So I can go 45 degrees from floor level into the adjacent wall, then 90 degrees back at ceiling level.  Exactly how that will constrain my new layout will not, unfortunately, be known til I open up the walls and floor.  The pipe is about a foot from the wall so 45 degrees is going to be a PIA.  Maybe I can hide it in a shower seat.

Comment: I can no longer edit that comment, but I guess on rereading the answer, the upper jog must be 88 degrees not 90.